# Append class name to an iframe id that is included under a div class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code

```
<div id="ad">
<div id="adsensebanner">
<iframe id="google_ad_randomnumber">
</iframe>
</div>
</div>
```

and I'm searching of a way to make it like this, using jQuery and CSS attributes matching:

```
<div id="ad">
<div id="adsensebanner" class="addedclass">
<iframe id="google_ad_randomnumber">
</iframe>
</div>
</div>
```

Any ideas for searching for div that has another parent div and appending a class to the child one?

Comment: $('#addsensebanner').addClass('addedclass') ??

Comment: Are you doing this in code in the parent document or the iframe? (I'm assuming parent document, but...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your comments on various answers suggest your HTML is invalid and has more than one `id="adsensebanner"` in it, but just one `id="ad"` in it.

Your best bet is to make the HTML valid. There can be only **one** element with `id="adsensebanner"` in it.

However, if for some reason you want to only target that one element when it's inside `id="ad"`:

```
document.querySelector("#ad #adsensebanner").classList.add("addedclass");
```

or with jQuery:

```
$("#ad #adsensebanner").addClass("addedclass");
```

That says "Add 'addedclass' to `#adsensebanner` only if it's inside `#ad`." There can be valid use-cases (if the one element with `id="adsensebanner"` may or may not be within `#ad` and you don't want to add the class if not), but they're rare.

If you correct the HTML to only have one `id="adsensebanner"`, and you always want to add the class, then:

```
document.getElementById("adsensebanner").classList.add("addedclass");
```

or with jQuery:

```
$("#adsensebanner").addClass("addedclass");
```

---

In a comment you've said:

> The double division check will definately work, however, my second div's ID name varies, so I would like to have it selected via an attr, like `div[id*='adsensebanner']`. Is there any workaround for this?

Yes, you can use any of the [attribute substring selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#attribute-substrings). For instance, if the `id` will always *start* with `adsensebanner` (`id="adsensebanner1"`, `id="adsensebanner2"`, etc.), then the selector to use with `querySelector` or jQuery would be `"#ad div[id^=adsensebanner]"`. (Or you can use the contains one you mentioned, `*=`, or `$=` if it always ends with something.)

Comment: Nicely explained answer.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Much appreciated.

The double division check will definately work, however, my second div's ID name varies, so I would like to have it selected via an attr, like div[id*='adsensebanner']. Is there any workaround for this? I tried a static name but im not sure if wrapping the code around <script> tags will make it work, since class was not appended to the div.

Comment: @JohnGreco - Yes, I've added that to the end of the answer.

Comment: Thanks @T.J.Crowder - amazing and detailed so far. I've wrapped it in my exact code but it doesnt seem to be working here, can you please give a check?  http://jsfiddle.net/6x4g7n8e/4/

Comment: @JohnGreco - Script code runs immediately when the parser encounters the `script` tag (in the normal case). The elements *below* that script in the HTML don't exist as of when the script runs ([more in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8716680/157247)). Move your `script` tags to the *end* of the `body`, just before the closing `</body>` tag (just at the end of the HTML frame, in a fiddle).

Comment: Sorry for it, im not really familiar with jQuery! Thanks for the help! supersaved me!

Comment: @JohnGreco - The URLs in that fiddle are invalid (open the web console to see errors). The script at the bottom seems okay, if you really want to use `*=` instead of `^=`.

Comment: Okay @T.J.Crowder - run fine! Thanks a lot! By the way, I ended up using position sticky of CSS, which will provide a lighter way of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
$('#adsensebanner', window.parent.document).addClass("addedclass");
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to identify the specific parent div, in order to prevent having it added on other parent divs. Your code will add it everywhere.

Comment: @ Suresh - I doubt the OP's code is running in the iframe, given it's a Google ad frame.

Comment: First division, called "ad" is from my code. Second division and iframe are parsed from AdSense.

Comment: @JohnGreco - Doesn't matter, it's your document. If you have multiple ad blocks on the page, you need to configure them appropriately (Google provides a way to do that without having duplicated `id` values).

Answer (score 0):

Simple JS can do the trick. And I can't see this div is inside the iFrame.

```js
var p = document.getElementById("ad");
p.querySelector("[id='adsensebanner']").classList.add("addedClass");
```

```html
<div id="ad">
  <div id="adsensebanner">
    <iframe id="google_ad_randomnumber">
</iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, however, I need it only for "ad" parent div ID.

Comment: @JohnGreco Updated my answer as per the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

This is only by JavaScript:

```
 document.getElementById("ad").getElementsByTagName("div")[0].classList.add("addedClass");
```

```js
$( "#ad div:nth-last-child(1)" ).addClass("addedClass");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="ad">
<div id="adsensebanner">
<iframe id="google_ad_randomnumber">
</iframe>
</div>
</div>

<div id="ad1">
<div id="adsensebanner">
<iframe id="google_ad_randomnumber">
</iframe>
</div>
</div>
```

This will add a class only to div which have parent div id="ad"

Comment: Because he asked `and I'm searching of a way to make it like this, using jQuery and CSS attributes matching:`. May he forgot to tag JQuery or CSS. Be transparent. Can be done by only javascript and CSS too.

Comment: @JohnGreco, with and without JQuery.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys. I ended up using position fixed of CSS :)